# How do I change the duration of a Live Photo?

Tags: ios, swift, phlivephoto, apple-live-photos

I was recently reading the documentation of `isLivePhotoAutoTrimmingEnabled` https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/1648778-islivephotoautotrimmingenabled

> By default, a Live Photo capture is about three seconds in duration
>   (centered on the time of the capture request).

I was wondering if there is a way to make it 5 or 10 instead of only 3 seconds. How could I do that ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: I think not. What Apple means when they say "by default" is "we control the duration based on how the Camera app user is handling the device". If you want control like this, your best bet is to capture the camera output yourself as 5-10 seconds video.